# Parallelized merge sort implementation in Go

Tags: go

I'm currently learning Go. To enhance my understanding of Go goroutine, I write a parallelized version of classic merge sort where I try to split the workload into parallel goroutines.

Implementation

```
package sorting

import (
    "cmp"
)

const degradeThreshold int = 8

func ParallelMergesort[T cmp.Ordered](input []T) {
    if len(input) < 2 {
        return
    }

    // temporary array for saving intermediate merged results
    tmp := make([]T, len(input))
    parallelMergesort(input, tmp, 0, len(input))
}

func parallelMergesort[T cmp.Ordered](input, tmp []T, start, end int) {
    // degrade to insertion sort if the number of elements to sort is low
    if end-start <= degradeThreshold {
        insertionSort(input, start, end)
        return
    }

    splitPoint := start + (end-start)/2

    ch := make(chan struct{}, 2)
    var sortInHalf = func(s, e int) {
        parallelMergesort(input, tmp, s, e)
        // signal the completion of sorting current half
        ch <- struct{}{}
    }

    // sort the left half [start, splitPoint)
    // and the right half [splitPoint, end) in parallel
    go sortInHalf(start, splitPoint)
    go sortInHalf(splitPoint, end)

    // wait until the sorting of both halves is completed
    <-ch
    <-ch

    parallelMerge(input, tmp, start, splitPoint, end)
}

func parallelMerge[T cmp.Ordered](input, tmp []T, start, mid, end int) {
    parallelMergeSubarrays(input, tmp, start, mid, mid, end, start)
    copy(input[start:end], tmp[start:end])
}

// parallelMergeSubarrays merges the subarray input[lStart, lEnd) with subarray input[rStart, rEnd)
// and write the merged result into tmp[tStart, tStart + lEnd - lStart + rEnd - rStart)
func parallelMergeSubarrays[T cmp.Ordered](input, tmp []T, lStart, lEnd, rStart, rEnd, tStart int) {
    // if both subarrays are empty
    if lStart >= lEnd && rStart >= rEnd {
        return
    }

    // make sure [lStart, lEnd) always represents the larger range
    if rEnd-rStart > lEnd-lStart {
        lStart, lEnd, rStart, rEnd = rStart, rEnd, lStart, lEnd
    }

    lPivotPoint := lStart + (lEnd-lStart)/2
    v := input[lPivotPoint]
    rPivotPoint := findPivotPoint(input, rStart, rEnd, v)
    tPivot := tStart + (lPivotPoint - lStart) + (rPivotPoint - rStart)
    tmp[tPivot] = v

    ch := make(chan struct{}, 2)
    mergeInHalf := func(start1, end1, start2, end2, tStart int) {
        parallelMergeSubarrays(input, tmp, start1, end1, start2, end2, tStart)
        ch <- struct{}{}
    }

    // merge the two halves in parallel
    go mergeInHalf(lStart, lPivotPoint, rStart, rPivotPoint, tStart)
    go mergeInHalf(lPivotPoint+1, lEnd, rPivotPoint, rEnd, tPivot+1)

    // wait until the merge of both halves is completed
    <-ch
    <-ch
}

// findPivotPoint locates the leftmost index i in t[start:end)
// such that t[i] >= target using binary search
func findPivotPoint[T cmp.Ordered](t []T, start, end int, target T) int {
    // loop invariant:
    // t[start, l) < target
    // t[r, end) >= target
    // [l, r) unchecked
    l, r := start, end
    for l < r {
        mid := l + (r-l)/2
        if t[mid] >= target {
            r = mid
        } else {
            l = mid + 1
        }
    }
    return l
}

func insertionSort[T cmp.Ordered](t []T, start, end int) {
    for i := start + 1; i < end; i++ {
        // the element to be swapped with earlier sorted elements
        v := t[i]
        j := i - 1
        for ; j >= start && t[j] > v; j-- {
            t[j+1] = t[j]
        }
        t[j+1] = v
    }
}
```

Unit test

```
package sorting

import (
    "math/rand"
    "slices"
    "testing"
)

func TestParallelMergesort(t *testing.T) {
    var input = []int{5, 4, 1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 1, 8, 9}
    ParallelMergesort(input)

    if !slices.IsSorted(input) {
        t.Errorf("failed to sort the randomly generated integer slice")
    }

    var input2 = make([]int, 0, 100000)
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        input2 = append(input2, rand.Int())
    }
    ParallelMergesort(input2)
    if !slices.IsSorted(input2) {
        t.Errorf("failed to sort the randomly generated integer slice")
    }
}
```

Go version: 1.21.3

I'm looking for feedback on the code quality and style, clarity, as well as the usage of goroutine and channels.

Thanks for taking time reviewing my code. Appreciate any feedback

Answer (score 0):

You seem to keep spawning new goroutines again and again. This ain’t efficient. Instead, I suggest you create only one thread per logical core.

Comment: Thanks for the review. I think Go's concurrency model only supports goroutine and does not expose any thread (either kernel thread or green thread) functionality to the user. What you said could be true for other language

Comment: routines != threads. There's a talk about golang + pprof exploring this by taking an extreme example, generating the mandelbrot set (4K) linearly, then a routine per pixel, the latter feels horribly inefficient, but isn't as bad as you think. through profiling, the final version spins up a routine per row, so 2k+ routines, giving the best performance. The runtime/scheduler manages the actual system threads